# How to get latest tag name?

Tags: git

How to get latest tag name (like version) of current branch?

Comment: It is not necessary duplicate. I maybe in feature branch, but still like to know what is latest branch of this repo, which may be in master branch.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**[`git describe`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html)** should be enough

> The command finds the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit.
>   If the tag points to the commit, then only the tag is shown.
>   Otherwise, it suffixes the tag name with the number of additional commits on top of the tagged object and the abbreviated object name of the most recent commit.
>
> **With `--abbrev` set to 0, the command can be used to find the closest tagname without any suffix**:

```
[torvalds@g5 git]$ git describe --abbrev=0 v1.0.5^2
tags/v1.0.0
```

For tags matching a certain pattern:

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0 --match release-*
```

([Peterino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202834/peterino)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277773/how-to-get-latest-tag-name/4277828#comment20312518_4277828))

For the latest tag on *all* the branches (not just the latest branch)

```
git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)
```

(from [kilianc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/879005/kilianc)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7979255/6309))

Comment: The latest tag (any, not only annotated) matching a certain pattern (e.g. "release-..."):
    git describe --tags --abbrev=0 --match release-*

Comment: is it possible to get last remote tag?

Comment: @gayavat no, local tag only, but all yu have to do is fetch the remote tags, and if one of those remote tags is applied on a recent commit part of the branch you are describing, then that tag will be part of the describe output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7979255/350580 provides a more accurate solution. While `git describe --abbrev=0` only tell you the current branch. That answer tell you the latest tag for all branches.