# How to remain only specific count of lastest tags automatically in github?

Tags: git, github, git-tag

As i metioned in title, is it possible that remaining specific count of lastest tags automatically in github? ex. 5

There are more than 500 tags in my github repository. it is annoying to find specific tags. Thanks you!

> I found git command that could sort tags with versions. If you want to filter with specific words, use grep.

```
git tag -l --sort=version:refname | grep "something"
```

Comment: What's a "latest" tag? How is one tag later than another tag? When does a tag stop being "latest"? You'll need to define this first, before you can even begin answering the question.

Comment: @torek Thanks for your feedback. Latest what i wrote means newest tags. My tags created with numbers such as production-1, production-2. In this case, latest tag is production-2.

Comment: So if I create "production-8", and then one week later, create "production-7", which one is newer?

Comment: @torek In this case, "production-7" is newer. :) But my tag options is auto-increment, So this situation you mentioned will not happen.

Comment: OK - but it helps, because *annotated* tags carry a date stamp. So if these are annotated tags, read their date stamps (with `%(taggerdate)`; see the for-each-ref documentation). If they're not annotated tags, you might have to fall back on trying to parse the ref name and read the numeric value. In all cases, `for-each-ref refs/tags` will let you scan through all the tags and operate on them. I'd probably use awk or something to collect the right ones and pick out the keepers and discards.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned [how to get the "latest" (meaning most recent) tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277828/6309) across all branches.

By counting those, you would get your count:

```
git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1) | wc -l
```