# Automatically generate git tags in the form vx.x.x

Tags: git, bash, deployment, jenkins, git-tag

Hello StackOverflow people, I'm working on a project that involves CI with Jenkins, git, rsync and so I'm trying to figure out a way to automatically generate the tag versions for each succesfull deploy in the form of [vX.X.X](http://semver.org/)

My question is are there any tools avialable that will do this for you, or you have to do this by hand (bash,grunt, etc.)?

So that you can call this on Jenkins and it will tell you what Tag your building.
I was thinking about having files in each folder staging/ and release/ .So then some how I could parse the files (bash script, grunt, etc.) to know what version I'm on right so that I can do :

- the next build (name the correct next tax, i.e if my previous build was v1.2.3 I would do v.1.2.4 .... and so on)
- rollback to a previos tag in case a build failed. (if I'm doing v1.2.4 and it failed rollback to v1.2.3)

I'm sure there are a lot of options out there please share :D

**EDIT:**  Well I'm was looking for something like

```
git tag --semantic--versioning --ma 0 --mi 0 --p 3
```

so that when you would type in

```
git describe
```

you would get something like

```
v0.0.3
```

this way you could have another tool to work with in Jenkins parameterized builds

Comment: This isn't 100% clear; are you asking for a tool that will actually *create* a tag, or simply to determine what the most recent tag is?

Comment: For most recent tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404796/how-to-get-the-latest-tag-name-in-current-branch-in-git might be helpful.

Comment: How is `git tag --semantic--versioning --ma 0 --mi 0 --p 3` better than `git tag v0.0.3`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  your right, my problem is that while working with a Jenkins job I'm not sure how to tell it to create -after a succesfull build- for example a tag like v1.2.3 how is jenkins going to know what is the latest tag in the current branch, so that it can create v1.2.4 or v.1.3.0 when it reaches 1.2.9 for example and more important how to save this(current tag V) to rollback in case something happens

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, your code base has some version information, and what you're looking for is a way to simplify working with a version string; being able to parse it and increment/decrement it, and then make git tags out of it. If you're okay with calling `git tag` yourself, then you're just left with handling the version string. For this, I've used the "Version" module in Perl:

http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Perl-Version-1.013/lib/Perl/Version.pm

It basically allows you to construct a version object from a string (which can be in a number of formats), and provides functions to manipulate and access the version, or parts of it. You can use this straight in your Jenkins jobs using `perl -e`, or create scripts if you wish to reuse them. A simple example that increments the minor version using perl and makes a tag out of it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
oldversion="v1.2.1"
newversion=$(perl -MPerl::Version -e "my \$ver = Perl::Version->new(\"${oldversion}\"); \$ver->increment(1); print \"\$ver\"");
echo "Tagging with ${newversion}"
git tag "${newversion}"
```

This takes the version string of `v1.2.1` and increments the minor value to create `v1.3.0`, printing it to the screen and making a git tag as well. Notice that the patch portion is zeroed out automatically when incrementing the minor value, and the format of the version string is retained.