# How can I get the latest tag of the form vX.X.X.X?

Tags: git, tags, git-branch, git-tag

Here is a list of tags I get when I do `git describe --tags`:

```
v1.1.8
v1.1.9
v1.2.0
v1.2.0.1
v1.2.0.10
v1.2.0.11
v1.2.0.12
```

If I do

```
git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`
```

I may get tag with either 3 digit or 4 digit.  I only want to pick up the latest 4 digit tag. How can I always get the latest 4 digit git tag?

What I mean by the 4 digit tag is anything with vX.X.X.X

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "4-digit tag". In your example, is `v1.2.0.12` the latest "4-digit tag"?

Comment: Correct. The pattern matching X.X.X.X

Comment: Did you get that command from somewhere else on the site? From [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7979255/2541573)), perhaps? If so, it would be good to link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: You write

> I only want to pick up the *latest* 4-digit tag.

(my emphasis)

However, your question really only makes sense for *annotated* tags, which, contrary to *lightweight* tags, do have a date associated to them. In that respect, a *lightweight* tag is not that much different from a branch reference.

- To list all tags (either *annotated* or *lightweight*) in your repository that match the pattern `vX.X.X.X` (where `X` stands for one or more digits), run

  ```
  git tag | grep -E "v([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+"
  ```

If you want something else, please clarify your question.