# Get tags below a particular tag in git

Tags: git, git-tag

I am trying to find out tags that are less than a given number.
I have assigned numbers from `1` to `2000` as tags to Git . Now, I want to display all the tags that are below a particular tag number.

For example, my query number (tag) is `1234` and I want git to display all the tags that are less that `1234`. How can I do that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26977922/2541573

Comment: Please use proper Markdown formatting in your questions: backticks should be used for inline code, not for emphasis, etc.

Comment: Git alone isn't capable of doing this so the answer entirely depends on the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure I understand, you want to compare the tag names numerically?  You don't want to compare tags in terms of commit ancestry?

If so, the following shell code should work:

```
git tag | grep '^[0-9]*$' | while IFS= read -r tag; do
    [ "${tag}" -ge 1234 ] || printf %s\\n "${tag}"
done
```

The above tells Git to print all the tags, filters out the non-number tags, loops over each numerical tag comparing it to a certain numerical value.  If it's less than that value, the tag name is printed.