# Git command doesn't work in subprocess in Python

Tags: git, python-2.7

We've been using python to automate some git work for quite some time in my group, and everything has worked fine.  Unfortunately, I've come across something I would like to use, but doesn't work when put into a python subprocess.  Here's the command:

```
git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`
```

When I use it in my git bash (we're using Windows) it works fine, but when I put it in a python subprocess, it complains that `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1` is not a valid command.  I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me as to why, and preferably, a way of using it.  I got the line from this question:

[How to get the latest tag name in current branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404796/how-to-get-the-latest-tag-name-in-current-branch-in-git)

I'm trying to get the LATEST tag on a branch, that is closest to the current HEAD.  I've got a hacky workaround right now that lists all of the tags and then sorts them numerically, but that's only working because we haven't put out any non-numeric tags, which won't necessarily be the case always.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Popen` constructor by default doesn't use a shell to parse the command you're giving it. This means that shell metacharacters like the backquote and such things will not work. You can either pass `shell = True` or first run `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1` and then create the whole command after that.