# Using back-ticks in Python subprocess

Tags: python, git, bash, subprocess, popen

I want to run this git command through a Python script and get the output of it:

```
git diff --name-only mybranch `git merge-base mybranch develop`
```

The purpose of the command is to see what changes have been made on `mybranch` since the last merge with develop.

To achieve this I'm using `subprocess.Popen`:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["git", "diff", "--name-only", "mybranch", "`git merge-base mybranch develop`"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

However, this does not work. The variable `output.communicate()[0]` simply gives me a printout of git usage -- essentially telling me the input command is wrong.

I saw that a similar question [exists here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328207/git-command-doesnt-work-in-subprocess-in-python), but it only told me to use `shell=True` which didn't solve my problem.

I also attempted to run the two commands in succession, but that gave me the same output as before. It is possible that I am missing something in this step, though.

Any help or tips are appreciated.

Comment: why are you trying to use shell=True and passing a list of args? Also why is git in a separate list?`

Comment: The answer in the linked question said that using back-ticks would only work with shell=True. They are in separate lists for no particular reason, I'll edit to avoid confusion.

Comment: You should either use a string with shell=True or remove shell=True and pass a list of individual args

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer. I must have missed this in the docs.

Comment: Note that backticks are deprecated in Bash: the `$(cmd)` syntax is less prone to being mis-read, and you can nest it if necessary. See [BashFAQ/082](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) "Why is $(...) preferred over (backticks)?" in the BashGuide for further details. Also, backticks are a pain to write in SO comments. :)

Comment: You might consider having a second `subprocess.Popen()` call in your Python to invoke `git merge-base` and collect its output for use in the later call; that's what your other command is doing, just telling the shell to create the subprocess that runs that second call. More efficient to do it yourself than create a shell to do it for you. (And if this is a web service and `mybranch` is coming from an untrusted source, you should also do that for security reasons; shell injection is no joke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Backticks and subprocess

The backtick being a **shell feature**, you may not have a choice but to use `shell=True`, however pass in **a shell command string**, not a list of args

So for your particular command (assuming it works in the first place)

```
process = subprocess.Popen("git diff --name-only mybranch `git merge-base mybranch develop`", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Notice when you call `Popen()` you get a process, shouldn't be called `output` IMO

**Here's a simple example that works with backticks**

```
>>> process = subprocess.Popen('echo `pwd`', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
>>> out, err = process.communicate()
>>> out
'/Users/bakkal\n'
```

**Or you can use the $(cmd) syntax**

```
>>> process = subprocess.Popen('echo $(pwd)', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
>>> out, err = process.communicate()
>>> out
'/Users/bakkal\n'
```

**Here's what did NOT work (for backticks)**

```
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(['echo', '`pwd`'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
>>> out, err = process.communicate()
>>> out
'\n'
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(['echo', '`pwd`'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
>>> out, err = process.communicate()
>>> out
'`pwd`\n'
```

Comment: @PM2Ring Added a sample using `$(cmd)` with `subprocess`

Comment: Thanks. I decided to move my comment to the question, since it's probably more appropriate there.

Comment: you *have* a choice, you can [drop `shell=True`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31521714/4279)

Comment: You'd have to do the backtick expansion manually, because from my trials it doesn't seem you can expand backticks or `$(cmd)` without `shell=True`, backticks being the crux of the question

Answer (score 2):

On POSIX, the argument list is passed to `/bin/sh -c` i.e., only the first argument is recognized as a shell command i.e., the shell runs `git` without any arguments that is why you see the usage info. You should pass the command as a string if you want to use `shell=True`. From [the `subprocess` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> On POSIX with `shell=True`, the shell defaults to `/bin/sh`. If `args` is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.
>   This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be
>   when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or
>   backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If `args` is a
>   sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
>   additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell
>   itself. That is to say, `Popen` does the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
> ```

You don't need `shell=True` in this case.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_output

merge_base_output = check_output('git merge-base mybranch develop'.split(), 
                                 universal_newlines=True).strip()
diff_output = check_output('git diff --name-only mybranch'.split() +
                           [merge_base_output])
```