# Get all tags when they refer to same commit

Tags: git, tags

I've seen in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404796/how-to-get-the-latest-tag-name-in-current-branch-in-git) how to retrieve the last tag of the current branch.

I have a situation in which two tags refer to the same commit, and that's the last one. If I use the command

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
```

I obtain only one tag. Is there a way to retrieve the list of all tags if the last tagged commit has more than one tag associated?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags | xargs git rev-parse | xargs git tag --points-at`? If you know the commit, you can just do a git tag --points-at  (although describe only appears to list annotated tags and not the lightweight tags).

In addition, if you do a `git log --decorate -n 1 --oneline <commit>` it will should you all the refs that refer to that commit. You could parse that as well.

Although I'm sure there is a more direct approach here.

Comment: It does not seem to work. I have only one tag and not both of them with the first command. With the second one instead I've the following result `9a052d1 (tag: v1.5.9, tag: IDL_1.15) SQL updated.`. So I have piped the two commands and I obtain the previous output with this command: `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags | xargs git log --decorate -n 1 --oneline`. I now must find a way to extract from the output the list of tags.

Comment: So is one of your tags a lightweight and the other an annotated one? If so, the git describe will only list the annotated one. Regardless, tag --points at will work for either kind of tag, you just need to know the commit. So if you have another way to find the commit, then use that.