# get git tags without the commit hash

Tags: git, git-tag

I want the lightweight git tag of a branch (not annotated) but

`git describe --tag` gives me the commit hash as well. How do I query just the tag

getting:

```
0.1.2-milestone-343-f20ef9ef2d
```

want:

```
0.1.2-milestone
```

Solution:

```
git describe --tag --abbrev=0

--tags show lightweight tags too
--abbrev=0 removes the hash
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the latest tag name in current branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404796/how-to-get-the-latest-tag-name-in-current-branch-in-git)

Comment: I'm assuming with that above comment that you want the most recent tagged from a particular branch. Please refine your question if this is not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this worked for my specific requirement

```
git describe --tag --abbrev=0

--tags show lightweight tags too
--abbrev=0 removes the hash
```

Answer (score 3):

That's the name of your tag `0.1.2-milestone-343-f20ef9ef2d`

`git describe` will display the tag name (will display only annotated tags)

`git show-ref --tags` will display the hash as well

`git describe --tag --abbrev=0` will display what you want

Comment: so read up 

https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html

git describe shows only annotated tags not lightweight tags and adds additional commits on top of tagged object. Not what I want.

what I was looking for is git describe --tag --abbrev=0 
but thanks