# Get "git describe --abbrev=0" results into a variable

Tags: windows, git, cmd

Goal: get the output of `git describe --tag=Foo --abbrev=0` into a Windows environment variable.

My attempt:

```
C:\Projects\Foo> FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %F IN \
   (`git describe HEAD --match "Foo*" --abbrev=0 --debug`) DO SET Var=%F
```

Result:

> describe HEAD No exact match on refs or tags, searching to describe
>
> finished search at d501f4f270405435692e5eb369fafbb53f0c74a2  annotated
>   463 Foo0.0-beta traversed 562 commits
>
> describe 0 fatal: Not a valid object name 0

That's a weird fatal error. Without the `FOR`, Git works:

`git describe HEAD --match "Foo*" --abbrev=0 --debug`

> No exact match on refs or tags, searching to describe
>
> finished search at d501f4f270405435692e5eb369fafbb53f0c74a2  annotated        463
>   Foo0.0-beta traversed 562 commits
>
> Foo0.0-beta

Now the `describe 0 fatal` can be traced back to the `--abbrev=0` argument, but that's an essential argument. It seems that `FOR` has broken the `--abbrev=0` argument into two parts, which resulted in Git treating the `0` as a hash value, and trying to find a tag to describe that hash.

References: [Getting the output of a command into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file), [Getting a tag name with git describe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404796/how-to-get-the-latest-tag-name-in-current-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the = using a caret (^)

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %F IN \
   (`git describe HEAD --match "Foo*" --abbrev^=0 --debug`) DO SET Var=%F
```

Comment: only one vote and not even selected smh. thank you