# Get latest tag in .gitlab-ci.yml for Docker build

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to add a tag when building a Docker image, I'm doing this so far but I do not know how to get the latest tag on the repository being deployed.

```
docker build -t company/app .
```

My goal

```
docker build -t company/app:$LATEST_TAG_IN_REPO? .
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'latest tag on the repository' exactly? Is that a git tag? Would you then be looking for the first git tag that is an ancestor of the commit currently being deployed?

Comment: renefritze yes, the latest tag created with `git tag`and being saved in the origin repository (gitlab)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try using `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` or `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`, this is part of the [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) accessible during builds.

If you want to see what are all the available environment variables during build step this should work as one of your jobs:

```
script:
    - env
```

Comment: `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` is only non-empty if the build is for a tag. If the currently building commit is not tagged, it will be empty. `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` is similarly only the the tag if it's a tagged build, otherwise that's the branch name.

Comment: renefritze  yeah, I had to add `only: - tags`

Answer (score 22):

Since you're looking for the "latest" git tag which is an ancestor of the currently building commit you probably want to use

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```

to get it and use it like:

```
docker build -t company/app:$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0) .
```

[Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404796/how-to-get-the-latest-tag-name-in-current-branch-in-git) for the finer points on `git describe`

Comment: This only gets the annotated tag. Need to use `git describe --tags --abbrev=0` to get the tag even if lightweight.

Comment: Let's suppose I build a commit from tag 0.2 and then I want to rollback to 0.1. If I rebuild with the commit pointing to 0.1, what tag will the git describe command return? 0.1 or 0.2?

Answer (score 1):

The [pre-defined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` is empty if no git tag points to the current commit in the pipeline. If you either want the current tag or the current SHA of the commit (as a fallback), you can use `IMAGE_VERSION=${CI_COMMIT_TAG:-"$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"}`