# How to automatically select the latest tagged version of an GitHub action?

Tags: github, github-actions

Since the documentation for GitHub actions is far far behind, I couldn't find anything about it online.

Is there a way for GitHub actions to select the latest tagged version?

If I want to select a version I would do:

```
  uses: MarvinJWendt/run-node-formatter@1.2.0
```

If I always want the latest commit I would use the master branch

```
  uses: MarvinJWendt/run-node-formatter@master
```

But what do I have to do, to get the latest **tagged** version, as the master branch is in development and not stable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no way to run a [`git describe --tags`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) (in order to [get the latest tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7261049/6309)), one workaround would be:

- each time you apply a tag, you reset a dedicate "`tags`" branch to that tag
- in your GitHub Action workflow, you would "`use`" the "`tags`" branch, which by its construction, would reference the latest tag.

Comment: Yes that's a nice workaround, but it's kinda too much effort to maintain. I'm hoping on something like `@latest` to be introduced in the future :)

Comment: @MarvinJWendt I agree. This is just pending that future evolution.