# How to get latest tag name not using `git fetch --tags`

Tags: git

There has been an answer said how to get a latest tag, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7979255/7909869. But the premise is we must use `git fetch --tags` first after I use `git clone REPO --depth=1`. My REPO has many tags that means `git fetch --tags` will take a lot of time to download tags, and my request here is just to get the latest **tag name** not the whole code.

Comment: Does `git describe --tags` work?

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh Not work, there are no tags information after cloning repo.

Comment: If the tags follow a strict naming rule, you can try `git ls-remote --tags $url` to query all tags and then use some sort method to get the latest tag. `git ls-remote` provides [--sort=<key>](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html#Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt---sortltkeygt) to do the sorting.

Comment: @ElpieKay That's the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at `git describe`:

- `git describe --abbrev=0` it should return closest annotated tag
- or to  get the latest annotated tag which targets only the current commit in the current branch, use

  `git describe --exact-match --abbrev=0`