# Get git last tag into Azure pipeline variable

Tags: git, powershell, tags, azure-pipelines

I want to get the last tag and assign it to a variable created in my Azure Pipeline
this is what I'm doing 
Create variable
[image]

Added a powershell task
[image]

And I get this error 
[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get git last tag into Azure pipeline variable

The code I tested was also incorrect. To get the git last tag, you could use following powershell scripts, it works fine on my side:

```
cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
$Latesttag = $(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))

Write-Host "The latest git tag is $Latesttag "
```

[image]

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404796/how-to-get-the-latest-tag-name-in-current-branch-in-git/7979255#7979255) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked thanks, 
But what's wrong with  $(git for-each-ref refs/tags --sort=-taggerdate --format="%(refname:short)" --count=1) ? It seems to return also the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

It was not clear but part of the question was how to set an Azure pipeline variable in powerShell task

```
$tag = $(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version]$tag"
```

version is the variable to set