# Gitlab multi-project pipeline, how to trigger a downstream pipeline on a latest tag?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Trying to trigger a pipeline to run test in project B (downstream) from project A. Wanted to know if it is possible to it run on a particular tag in project B.
(Currently, it always gets triggered on master which is the default branch.)

Answer (score 3):

Invoke this command ( from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/   )

```
 curl --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form ref=master https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/9/trigger/pipeline
```

change ref=master to ref=your_tag, and 9 to project B id.

to get latest tag ( from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1805463/746618)

```
git describe $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two projects with same tag you can do it like that:

Project A:

```
tag-job:
  stage: build
  trigger:
    project: project-b-name
    branch: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    strategy: depend
  only:
    - tags
```

Project B:

```
downstream-job:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"'
  script:
    - run tests
```

You can specify any other particular branch in "branch: " variable of tag-job.