# Why does `git describe` show "warning: tag 'xxx' is externally known as 'refs/tags/xxx'"?

Tags: git, git-describe

I am trying to use `git describe` to [retrieve the latest tag name for the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1404796/1880761), but I'm facing unexpected warnings in the output.

```sh
-> git describe
warning: tag 'v0.0.6' is externally known as 'refs/tags/v0.0.6'
refs/tags/v0.0.6-0-g5392899

-> git describe --tags
warning: tag 'v0.0.6' is externally known as 'refs/tags/v0.0.6'
refs/tags/v0.0.6-0-g5392899

-> git describe --tags --abbrev=0
warning: tag 'v0.0.6' is externally known as 'refs/tags/v0.0.6'
refs/tags/v0.0.6-0-g5392899c48d700b48e0dda16129dac6a60bb3b1e
```

As indicated, the tags locally do not have the `refs/tags` prefix:

```sh
-> git tag -l
v0.0.1
v0.0.2
v0.0.3
v0.0.4
v0.0.5
v0.0.6
```

However, I'm not sure why the warning is being received or what I can do about it.

The tags were not deleted and recreated, nor have they been renamed.

The tags are created from our build environment (Jenkins).

Is there something I can do to correct or work around the warning?

```sh
-> git show
commit 5392899c48d700b48e0dda16129dac6a60bb3b1e (HEAD -> master, tag: v0.0.6, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
...

-> git --version
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
```

**Edit:**

Our Jenkins build which creates the tags uses jgit. The configuration for checking out the branch/code is as follows:
[image: jenkins git checkout]

The tag creation is done using Git Publisher:
[image: jenkins git tag]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the same error using `git version 2.25.1`. The only difference is that the error message returned is:

> warning: tag 'refs/tags/1.0' is really '1.0' here

This warning comes from the [`append_name`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.30.1/builtin/describe.c#L272) function and I guess the problem is that `name_checked` field is false. I tried to find some logic behind that field but I did not make it, besides I am not that good with C and I would have lost a day at least.

The warning you are seeing might be caused by something else, but it came out after I (manually) generated a discrepancy between `.git/packed-refs`, `.git/refs/tags/1.0` and the tag object. Specifically, I created a tag named `refs/tags/1.0`, but I modified the `.git/packed-refs` like this:

```
975b54bb9b78e245f5abd1b10d6f090c4e0bbf58 refs/tags/1.0 # instead of refs/tags/refs/tags/1.0
^f84bc266f21fa641076a9bef0de4bf2ce1fa5090
```

However, unlike you, I am not seeing only the correct tag with `git tag -l`, but also the forged one.

Two advices for you: firstly I would check that those 3 files (`.git/packed-refs`, `.git/refs/tags/your_tag` and the tag object file in `.git/objects`) do not contain any contradictory reference. In either case, please edit your question with how the Git plugin for Jenkins clones the remote repository. If I am not mistaken, it tries hard to optimize performances by reducing at the minimum the references it checks out (and maybe there is just a bug in the plugin).

Comment: I have added detail regarding how Jenkins performs checkout and tagging. I am wondering if the issue is in Git Publisher. We are using `refs/tags/TAG_NAME` in Jenkins Git Publisher config as a workaround for [other issues faced](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-37120) when using jgit. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the local tag files, I cloned a fresh copy of the repo and do not see any tags in `.git/refs/tags` (even after `git fetch --tags`). It seems tags are only in `.git/packed-refs`. I see only two files in `.git/objects/pack` but am not sure how they are used (filename has different has than commit).

Comment: The workaround you have used might be the problem. How are tags named in `.git/packed-refs`? I do not think packed objects could cause it, but I would not bet.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the `.git/packed-refs` file: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJsGL.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJsGL.png).

Comment: Thanks, at this point I guess the tag object created is named `refs/tags/v0.0.x`. In that case try to reproduce the issue in a new clean repository with that git version, the tag object named `refs/tags/v0.0.1` (and not just `v0.0.1`) and the same name in the `packed-refs` file (as it is now). If it is not the case, then we are missing something.